Calculating confidence intervals for a population proportion?

The proportion of European men who are red-green colour-blind is 8%.
How large a sample would need to be selected to be 95% certain that it
contains at least this proportion of red-green colour-blind men?

To me, I don't even know where to start with this problem. It is telling us that the sample proportion is 0.08, so we can work out a confidence interval in terms of $n$. This makes sense. However, the next part of the problem makes absolutely no sense to me.  The sample must contain at least this proportion of red-green colour-blind men, but because the confidence interval is based around this proportion of 0.08, it doesn't make any sense at all this question. What am I missing?

A random sample of 200 bees from a colony is tested to find out how many are infected with mites. 40 bees are found to be infected. The colony of bees will collapse and not survive if 35% or more are infected. Show why it is possible at the 99% confidence level, that the colony of bees might collapse?

The solution recognises an overlap between the confidence intervals, if we were to use the sample proportion as 0.2 or 0.35. However if we are 99% confident that the true population proportion lies in both intervals respectively, we should be really confident that the true population proportion is in the overlap. The overlap is far off 35% so yet again I don't understand how the population of bees might collapse.
Both these problems are proving to be extremely confusing. What am I misunderstanding?
Edit: the solution is as follows for problem one
$$1.96\times\sqrt{\frac{0.08\times0.92}{n}}\leq0.08$$
Before determining the value of $n$ as $45$. However this solution makes absolutely no sense to me, this question has nothing to do with the width of an interval, let alone an interval of width 0.16. So where is 0.08 coming from?
Is it possible that the question is poorly written. What is the question really trying to say?
Furthermore problem two has still not be addressed. It is proving to be extremely confusing.

That first question is interesting. My initial thought is that there is no sample size for which you could be $95$% confident that there is at least an $8$% proportion of red-green colour-blind people in the sample.

@AdamRubinson Could you please explain your intuition behind this first thought?

From a sample of size $n,$ the expected number of people that are red-green colour-blind is $0.08n.$ The probability that there are at least $0.08n$ who are red-green colour-blind is approximately $0.5,$ maybe slightly less, maybe slightly more, but a discrepancy of $0.45$ sounds implausibly large.

The asymmetry in the distribution is quite small, nothing like what is called for here.  Normally one would ask for confidence that the color blind pool is at least $7%$ or something like that.
